# Save the values of this javascript

Tags: javascript

Well I have this code that changes the colors of a cell, but what I'm looking for is that it doesn't delete the results when I restart the page, because I'm making a page so that users can mark the hours they have available weekly.

I don't know if someone can help me, to save those values, thanks.

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0 Transitional//EN">
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Untitled</title>
   <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
   function ilumina(celda){
    if (celda.style.backgroundColor=="yellow")
        {
        celda.style.backgroundColor="green";
        }
    else
        {
        celda.style.backgroundColor="yellow";
        }
    }
  </SCRIPT>
  </head>
  <body>
    <table border="1" width="50%">
        <tr>
            <td bgcolor="green" onclick="ilumina(this)">&nbsp;</td>
            <td bgcolor="green" onclick="ilumina(this)">&nbsp;</td>
            <td bgcolor="green" onclick="ilumina(this)">&nbsp;</td>
            <td bgcolor="green" onclick="ilumina(this)">&nbsp;</td>
        </tr>
        
  </table>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: You can use [localStorage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage) or Database to persist data.

Answer (score 0):

You can use

1. **arrays**, to save each elements color value
2. **JSON** ***encode*** / ***decode***, to convert arrays to strings-text (needed to
   save to localstorage, since it's used to save strings-text
3. **localstorage** ***set*** / ***get***

You can save your data each time you change the colors, then on load of the page you can check if you have previously saved any data.
If yes, then load the data and change the colors.

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0 Transitional//EN">
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Untitled</title>
   <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
   
    //DOMContentLoaded = when page elements are loaded
    document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(event) {
        //check if we have saved any 'celda_storage_localstorage' value
        if ( localStorage.getItem('celda_storage_localstorage') != null ) {
            celda_storage = JSON.parse( localStorage.getItem('celda_storage_localstorage') );
            
            //load colors from celda_storage
            for (let i=0; i < celda_storage.length; i++) {
                document.querySelectorAll('#celdas_table td')[i].style.backgroundColor = celda_storage[i];
            }
        }
    });
   
    function ilumina(celda){
        if (celda.style.backgroundColor=="yellow")
            {
            celda.style.backgroundColor="green";
            }
        else
            {
            celda.style.backgroundColor="yellow";
            }
            
        //save colors to celda_storage
        for (let i=0; i < document.querySelectorAll('#celdas_table td').length; i++) {
            celda_storage[i] = document.querySelectorAll('#celdas_table td')[i].style.backgroundColor;
        }
        
        console.log(celda_storage);
        
        //JSON.stringify = array to string
        localStorage.setItem('celda_storage_localstorage',JSON.stringify(celda_storage));
        //JSON.parse = string to array
        console.log( JSON.parse( localStorage.getItem('celda_storage_localstorage') ) );
    }
  </SCRIPT>
  </head>
  <body>
    <table id="celdas_table" border="1" width="50%">
        <tr>
            <td style="background-color : green" onclick="ilumina(this)">&nbsp;</td>
            <td style="background-color : green" onclick="ilumina(this)">&nbsp;</td>
            <td style="background-color : green" onclick="ilumina(this)">&nbsp;</td>
            <td style="background-color : green" onclick="ilumina(this)">&nbsp;</td>
        </tr>
        
  </table>
  </body>
</html>
```

Have fun and ask !

Comment: thanks for your answer I have tried the code you have put, but it does not work for me, can you explain a little more in detail what I should do, it is that I do not have much knowledge!

Answer (score 0):

If I do it with localstorage, it only saves the information for my browser.
I think I need to send the information to the backend, but with my knowledge I don't know how to do that.